# Custom class extending AsyncHttpResponseHandler and return modified bytes

Tags: java, android

I have searched with google for the past 3 hours to no avail, I am not sure if this is even possible.

I am using AsyncHttpResponseHandler in 10-12 different activities, and with all of them I am doing the same initial transforming of the "byte[] bytes" in the initial code, which is around 50lines of code per activity.

How would I do said transformation of bytes, and then return the final value on the activity where the custom class gets called?

How would I reference the message variable?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    client.post(URL, params, new VenueAsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int i, Header[] headers, byte[] bytes) {
            //How do I reference the transformed message here?
            switch (message) {
                case "success":
                    //Do something
                    break;
            }

        }
    });
}
}
```

when using the custom class

```
public class VenueAsyncHttpResponseHandler extends AsyncHttpResponseHandler {
@Override
public void onSuccess(int i, Header[] headers, byte[] bytes) {
    String byteToString = null;
    JSONObject response = null;
    String message = "";
    try {
        byteToString = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
        response = new JSONObject(byteToString);
        message = response.getString("response"); //return this to the activity
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException | JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onFailure(int i, Header[] headers, byte[] bytes, Throwable throwable) {

}
}
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. In particular, you need a class with a method. The code you have posted will not compile because these are missing.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I am not looking for help regarding my specific code, I am asking a question on how to achieve something. If I do manipulations to the response on the success method, how would I pull said manipulated response when I use the custom class?

Comment: I am **not** asking you to post your specific code. I **am** asking you to post code which **compiles**. Thank you for the recent edit.

Comment: "How do I reference the transformed message here?" Where is the transformed message currently? Is there a reason you are creating an instance of an anonymous inner class which extends `VenueAsyncHttpResponseHandler` rather than an instance an instance of `VenueAsyncHttpResponseHandler` itself?

Comment: I need to create a custom class to remove duplicated code all over the app, I for example (first piece of code) transform `bytes` into a `message` . Now I do not want to repeat this process everywhere and on each activity do something different with the message. So when using the custom class I need to use the transformed `message` on the activity? I hope I am making sense.

Comment: You already have a custom class called `VenueAsyncHttpResponseHandler`. There is no need to create an anonymous inner class which actually makes reuse harder.

Comment: Yes I do have a custom class called `VenueAsyncHttpResponseHandler` where I do all the transforming of the message returned back from the webservice. What I need to know is how do I get the message back from `VenueAsyncHttpResponseHandler` class and use it inside the activity?

Comment: I understand your question. I am looking into that further. In the mean time, I am just making a suggestion to help you simplify your code significantly. See my answer below.

Comment: To help clarify, what are you doing with the transformed message? Which class contains the code which creates the custom handler? Again, we need a [mcve] to help you. Please provide code **which compiles**.

Comment: Please read the link I have given twice above for suggestions about code examples. In order to answer your question, I need to know what class contains each snippet of code. This gives very important information about what you are doing.

Comment: I am busy compiling the code example now as per your request.

Comment: I hope my update makes more sense. Thank you for helping thus far

Answer (score 0):

Add a method to your activity class which does what you want with the message. Then call this method from onSuccess().

Also, do not create an anonymous inner class. Instead instantiate your custom class directly:

```
VenueAsyncHttpResponseHandler handler = new VenueAsyncHttpResponseHandler();
client.post(URL, params, handler);
```